# Print attachments from web/xpages

Tags: itext, xpages

In my applications I need to have a print feature that will print documents from a Notes View including their attachments (could be images, pdf's, office documents) as a single, ordered file.

From what I have found via an non-evil pretending search engine I found that iText supports many features including merging of pdf's, conversion to pdf and reading streams.

I am not sure if my internal only used application will fall under the AGPL license?.

I also concern other alternatives when they allow me merging pdf, document conversion and including images.

Any sample code for java agents, ssjs , java is welcome.

Comment: To know if your internal-only application will fall under the AGPL license, contact iText Software: https://itextpdf.com/contact. IANAL but my gut feeling is, as long as your _end users_ have an easy way to access the source code of your application, then you're more than likely good to go. And in your case, your end users are only the employees of your company. So if the receptionist uses your application, then the receptionist should be able to have access to the source code.

Comment: Asking for sample code, without showing what you have tried yourself, is heavily frowned upon here on Stack Overflow.

Comment: I would never go with AGPL licens if you don't like or is allowed to publishing the full source of the application on a public website

Comment: I do not dare that either

Answer (score 2):

Here's an example using server-side JavaScript in XPages with iText to generate PDF files.  iText is a Java class library, and it can be called from SSJS.  Of course, it could be written in Java and simply called from the XPage, too.  This is an SSJS solution. In the XPage `beforeRenderResponse` event:

```
importPackage(com.itextpdf);   // put the itext jar file in the Code/Jars folder
importPackage(java.io);
importPackage(java.net);
importPackage(javax.imageio);
importPackage(sun.misc);
importPackage(java.lang);

//Initialize
var hostname = context.getUrl().toString().split(facesContext.getExternalContext().getRequest().getRequestURI())[0];

var con = facesContext.getExternalContext();
var response:com.ibm.xsp.webapp.XspHttpServletResponse = con.getResponse();

var outfilename = "MyPDF.pdf";

// set response headers for browser to recognize data
// deliver uncached PDF
response.setContentType("application/pdf");
response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");

response.setDateHeader("Expires", -1);
response.setHeader( "Content-Disposition", "inline; filename="+outfilename );

// create new PDF
var newPDF:com.itextpdf.text.Document = new com.itextpdf.text.Document(com.itextpdf.text.PageSize.LEGAL, 36, 36, 7, 10);

// Setup the Output Stream for the PDF
var outputstream = response.getOutputStream();
var writer = com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfWriter.getInstance(newPDF, outputstream);
var htmlWorker = new com.itextpdf.text.html.simpleparser.HTMLWorker(newPDF);

// Open the PDF and write the PDF header info
newPDF.open();

// set PDF meta data
newPDF.addAuthor("Eric Numeric");
newPDF.addCreationDate();
newPDF.addCreator("My Company, Inc.");
newPDF.addTitle("PDF Title");

// Text styles examples
var fontBOLD    = com.itextpdf.text.FontFactory.getFont("Consolas", 12, com.itextpdf.text.Font.BOLD);
var fontLABEL   = com.itextpdf.text.FontFactory.getFont("Consolas", 10, com.itextpdf.text.Font.BOLD, com.itextpdf.text.BaseColor.GRAY);
var fontBOLD8   = com.itextpdf.text.FontFactory.getFont("Consolas", 8, com.itextpdf.text.Font.BOLD);
var totrowFont  = com.itextpdf.text.FontFactory.getFont("Consolas", 7, com.itextpdf.text.Font.BOLD, com.itextpdf.text.BaseColor.BLUE);
var parabreak   = new com.itextpdf.text.Paragraph(" ");
var hiliteG     = new com.itextpdf.text.BaseColor(202, 255, 211, 1);  com.itextpdf.text.BaseColor.setValue(202, 255, 211, 1)
var bgcolor:com.itextpdf.text.BaseColor  = com.itextpdf.text.html.WebColors.getRGBColor("#CAFFD3");


// Get logo image - scale down
var image:com.itextpdf.text.Image = com.itextpdf.text.Image.getInstance(new URL(hostname + "/img/Logo.png")); 

image.scaleToFit(900, 40);
//print("scaled image");

newPDF.add(parabreak);       
newPDF.add(parabreak);  

//Create a table with 2 cells, width = 100%
var hdrtable = new com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfPTable(2);      // 2 columns.
hdrtable.setWidthPercentage(100);

// Logo
var cell1 = new com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfPCell(image); 
cell1.setBorder(com.itextpdf.text.Rectangle.NO_BORDER);     // removes border
hdrtable.addCell(cell1);

var cell2 = new com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfPCell(new com.itextpdf.text.Paragraph("Hello"));
cell2.setHorizontalAlignment(com.itextpdf.text.Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
cell2.setVerticalAlignment(com.itextpdf.text.Element.ALIGN_BOTTOM);
hdrtable.addCell(cell2);

// add table to PDF doc
newPDF.add(hdrtable);

// close PDF doc
newPDF.close();

// close writer
writer.close();

// complete response
facesContext.responseComplete();
```

When the Xpage is opened, the PDF should be displayed using the browser's PDF viewer, rather than downloaded as a file.

You can also use iText to convert HTML pages into PDF if you already have those HTML pages developed: [https://developers.itextpdf.com/content/itext-7-converting-html-pdf-pdfhtml](http://itext7pdf)

File attachments of PDFs or images can be appended with iText.  To convert Office docs, spreadsheets, etc. may require another Java library for converting to PDF -- you can then append the new PDF using iText.

Answer (score 1):

The best solution is to use Open Office in headless mode and convert all files to PDFs.

Most common files (Office documents, etc.) are supported.

For PDF operations (merging, splitting etc.) PDFBox is a great alternative.

Answer (score 0):

POI4XPages might be able to help with attachments and combining them, etc. I think your big issue is how to get the Domino document into a proper format for printing (pdf) and keeping a proper rendering. Native Notes documents are not html/css. So, they have to be rendered into html/css and then coverted to pdf to combine with your other attachments. There are some methods in the DominoDocument class to generate html.

Answer (score 0):

I've used [jspdf](https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF) to generate PDF documents from XPages, albeit called via CSJS (using a couple of JSON RPC services to get the data).